# Can't log into my MacPro user account

Tags: macos, hard-drive, login, mac-pro

I have an older Mac Pro in 10.11. After a minor update, I can no longer log into my main user account (which is a standard account) with all my files; the rotator goes indefinitely. I can log into any of the other accounts, including the Admin. I have tried safe boot, reset NVRAM, repairing with disk utility, repaired with DiskWarrior, then with Drive Genius 3, then with DiskWarrior again. I have a clone that was made before the minor update, and yet it behaves the same as the main HD. The HDs are fairly full, but there should be room enough. I was regularly logging into my user account right up to the time I did the update, and the clone shouldn't have that update.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a permanent solution, BUT it will let you recover your files.

1. Login to your Admin account
2. Open Terminal
3. Type `chmod -R 777 /Users/username/`
4. Go to the directory that your user folders are stored in (`/Users/`)
5. Retrieve any files needed just using Finder.
6. Delete user account.

Or

1. Login to your Admin Account
2. Open System Preferences
3. Click Users & Groups
4. Click reset password on the user.
5. Change password.